# Change structure of JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I want to bind data from the database to a line chart,
but I'm having difficulty making the JSON format.
Please help me to change JSON like this:

```
{
  "LineListChart": [
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": 14
    },
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": 10
    }
   ]
}
```

to be like this:

```
{
  "LineListChart": [
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": [0,0,14,4,10]
    }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `reduce`
have a look below

```js
var data ={
  "LineListChart": [
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": 14
    },
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Pembunuhan",
      "data": 10
    }
   ]
}

var chartData= data.LineListChart.reduce((result, item)=> {
if (!result.LineListChart){
     result.LineListChart =[{name: item.name, data: [item.data]}];
     }else result.LineListChart[0].data.push(item.data);
    
    return result;
}, {})

console.log(chartData)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) you can transform your JSON like this:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
obj["LineListChart"] = new JArray(
    obj["LineListChart"]
    .Children<JObject>()
    .GroupBy(jo => (string)jo["name"], jo => jo["data"])
    .Select(g => new JObject(
        new JProperty("name", g.Key),
        new JProperty("data", new JArray(g))
    ))
);
json = obj.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qpuQy7

Answer (score 1):

Because the question is json.net, I provide an answer by C# with json.net

```
    string test = @"{
                'LineListChart': [
                {
                    'name': 'Pembunuhan',
                    'data': 0
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Pembunuhan',
                    'data': 0
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Pembunuhan',
                    'data': 14
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Pembunuhan',
                    'data': 4
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Pembunuhan',
                    'data': 10
                }
                ]
            }";

   JObject obj = JObject.Parse(test);

   JArray categories = (JArray)obj["LineListChart"];

   var query = from c in categories group c by c["name"]
                into g select new { name = g.Key.ToString(), 
                     data =g.Select(c => (string)c["data"]) };

   var res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { LineListChart = query.ToList() });
```

Comment: Close, but your code converts the `data` into a comma-delimited string instead of an array like the OP wanted.

Comment: What I meant was this line: `data = string.Join(",", g.Select(c => (string)c["data"]))`.  I think it should be: `data = g.Select(c => c["data"])` . (The fix you already made is good though.)